# What am I doing wrong with this conditional statement using a UILabel in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

What am I doing wrong with this conditional statement using a `UILabel` in Xcode?

Over simplified example, but I am trying to change the content of the `UILabel` in relation to text in the `UILabel`.

```
-(IBAction)answerQuestion:(id)sender{
    NSString *startingLableContent = @"Do dogs bark?";
    NSString *answer = @"Yes.";
    NSString *askAnother = @"What else do you want?";
    if (mainLable.text == startingLableContent) {
        mainLable.text = answer;
    }else if (mainLable.text == answer){
        mainLable.text = askAnother;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to search for "Objective-C compare strings"?

Comment: How would he know to search for "Objective-C comparing strings" when he didn't realize that was what he was doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it seemed natural to me if the comparison of two strings in Objective-C does not give the expected result.

Comment: @MartinR perhaps that is why you have 28k of reputation and not 4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare them using `isEqualToString`

like this:

```
if ([mainLable.text isEqualToString:startingLableContent])
```

otherwise you are testing memory locations instead of content.

Comment: Technically, you could also use `isEqual` in this case, but I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

to compare Strings in Objective-C, use **isEqualToString**

```
-(IBAction)answerQuestion:(id)sender{
    NSString *startingLableContent = @"Do dogs bark?";
    NSString *answer = @"Yes.";
    NSString *askAnother = @"What else do you want?";
    if ([startingLableContent isEqualToString:mainLable.text]) {
        mainLable.text = answer;
    }else if ([answer isEqualToString:mainLable.text]){
        mainLable.text = askAnother;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ([mainLable.text isEqualToString:startingLableContent]) {
// do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### ==

It turns out that you can't just say `if (someString == someOtherString)`. It will almost always return `NO`.

It has to do with some stuff about where the string is stored in memory. You can use `==` with int's and double's and those kind of things, but with NSString's, you need to do:

#### `if ([mainLabel.text isEqualToString:someOtherString])`

And so, your method *should* look like:

```
-(IBAction)answerQuestion:(id)sender{
    NSString *startingLableContent = @"Do dogs bark?";
    NSString *answer = @"Yes.";
    NSString *askAnother = @"What else do you want?";
    if ([mainLable.text isEqualToString:startingLableContent]) {
        mainLable.text = answer;
    }else if ([mainLable.text isEqualToString:answer]){
        mainLable.text = askAnother;
    }
}
```

Comment: If they're both pointing to the same NSString object, `==` will return true.

Comment: @MarcusAdams And how often does that happen? If that happens in a real-world situation to you, I would suggest staying away from lightning storms for a while. Compilers will automatically point strings to other strings if it knows *at compile time* that it's the same string. Otherwise, well....

Comment: You wouldn't be doing it if you knew at compile time that they were equal. This would be for run-time checking and there are plenty of reasons to do this. Hair's answer is correct and it was first.

Answer (score 0):

You compare the pointers, not actual strings. If you want to compare strings, consider using `isEqualToString` instead.